# Recording data in android app and web service at same time

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to record data in android app and webservice at same time? I am trying to do this but if data is recording in android app data then not recording in webservice and if recording in webservice stops recording in android app? Thx in advance

Comment: what do you mean by record data ? Do you want to save some data locally as well as on the server ?

Comment: I have to show sensor's x, y, and z values in android app and as well as in webservice(which is created with REST).

Comment: whenever the sensor data changes ?

Comment: Yes, I'll explain you..... I have created 1 webservice using REST and creating 1 android app which will get data from  sensor and that data should be send to android app and as well as webservice. I've done to show data in android app but not saving data in web service.

Comment: Ideally, whenever the sensor data changes, you should update the android app + make request to webservice with updated sensor value and there's no reason why it wont work.

Comment: yes i am trying but not working. I can post code if you can find problem from there. Actually i m very new to android so having problem. Thx in advance

Comment: Yeah. Please add the code of how/when you update the sensor values.

Comment: I am not able to add long code here so plz can u sggest me how can i do it.

Comment: is it possible to send me ur email so that i can unzip code and send u?

Comment: try {
       DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.##"); 

       String[] args = { f.format(calibratedDataArray[0]) + "",
         f.format(calibratedDataArray[1]) + "", f.format(calibratedDataArray[2]) + "", patientid +"" };
       String result =rd.Recordmydetails(args);
       
       if (!result.toLowerCase().contains("success")) 
       {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please wait for doctor to ask for monitoring", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error saving to WS" + e , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

Comment: what sensors are you using ? I am assuming some external sensors (not the once on the android device)?

Comment: its shimmer accelerometer external sensor

Comment: I am running shimmer code which get data from sensor every second. Each second i also calling webservice. so i get a networking error because both components run on the same thread. How to run two thread in  the same time. So calling webservice will not affect the shimmer graph displaying.

Comment: can you give us the exact error from the logcat.

Comment: There are 2 errors: (1) Array INFO: 0.22772277227722773 9.831683168316832 -1.94.59405 94059405
(2) Error in http connection android os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a network request on the main thread which is not supported by the Android Version you're using.

Why not ? Assuming we are doing network operation on a button click in our application. On button click a request would be made to the server and response will be awaited. Due to single thread model of android, till the time response is awaited our screen is non-responsive. So we should avoid performing long running operations on the UI thread. This includes file and network access.

So start a new Thread when you want to send data. Something like :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Send Data to Web Server Here. 
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: ok thx so much for suggestion will try and let u know...... once again thx so much for quick reply

Comment: Hi! If the previous problem was solved, please accept this answer and add a new question so that others also might be able to help. Also, add the logcat output to your main question. Comments are not meant for that.

Comment: thats done and new ques posted with "Restarting app after displaying data values and graph" Thx Shivam to help me to solve this prob